# Ruby: splitting a string without removing separators

Tags: ruby, string, split

I need to split a string without removing the separators. Is there a simple and "Ruby oriented" way to do this?

For example, given a string like this:

```
str = "(This is (a test))"
```

what I need is this:

```
["(", "This", "is", "(", "a", "test", ")", ")"]
```

I tried using the split method for strings, using the brackets `"("` and `")"` as separators, but then I get them removed from the returning array. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What happened to the spaces in your original string? They aren't present in the array of strings.

Comment: I wish them to be removed from the array.

Comment: This looks more like a token parsing problem...

Comment: Yes: I'm trying to figure out how to acquire a string in a binary tree, in a lisp-like way, saving the words in the leaves. To do this (not sure if the best way to do so) I need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
str.scan(/\(|\)|\w+/)
```

Comment: This regexp will ignore all other characters.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Good but just slightly cleaner is: /[()]|\w+/